# Run existing GEE script with parameters from NodeJs or Python server

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, google-earth-engine-python-api

I am fairly new to GEE and the Remote Sensing Domain.

Our team is currently having tons of scripts in the GEE code editor.
Now the requirement is to provide a self-hosted UI for gathering the user input and execute these scripts.
I am insisting on reusing this already built script by passing the parameters to this script.

So, I am wondering if that is possible.

In my node or python server, would I be able to execute this remote GEE script with some parameters?

Sample existing script at location: users/something/myFunction.js in GEE code Editor

```
exports.firstFunction = function() {
  print("This is the first function");
  return "Hello World";
};
```

Now I want to call this function from my Node or Python server with parameters.

```
async function functionOnNodeServer(){
     const a = require("link to gee script");
     var response = await a.firstFunction();
     console.log(response); // Prints hello world in server console.
}
```

Comment: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/npm_install

Comment: This will allow me to write GEE scripts in my server script. Since the team working on these scripts does not have much familiarity with the application development, I want to keep GEE scripts separate from the caller. Added advantage of this is also that, GEE scripts can be modified indepedantly from the server code.